# htaccess redirect from subdomain

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have problem with subdomain redirects.

Current redirects:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.website.com$
RewriteRule ^any/other/page/$ http://website.com/sub/any/other/page/ [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/$ http://website.com/sub/blog/ [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
..... and much more other rewriterule (50+)
```

redirect from subdomain work fine, but http://website.com/blog/ is also redirect to http://website.com/sub/blog/

Maybe someone can find the problem ?

P.S. using on wordpress, my redirect writed before wordpress redirects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 1 condition and 2 rules. Conditions only work for the first rewriterule following the last condition. You need another one with the way you are using them.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.website\.com$
RewriteRule ^any/other/page/$ http://website.com/sub/any/other/page/ [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.website\.com$
RewriteRule ^blog/$ http://website.com/sub/blog/ [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
```

Based on your comment.

If you want to consolidate you can do this.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.website\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(any/other/page|blog)/$ http://website.com/sub/$1/ [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, so no possible use multiple rewriterules for one RewriteCond ?

Comment: but I have more than 50 rewriterules, and redirect page sometimes not match with old

Comment: @Nefro there are many ways to consolidate but you'd have to look at your  other rules and see what you can combine. Some will work like that and some will have to be individual if they don't match old.